# Problems with posting a question: "please enter at least one tag"

Tags: support, asking-questions

I am posting this on behalf of user [Mehdi](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/67913/mehdi). He mentioned [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8658401#8658401) that he is able to post neither on main nor in meta, so I am asking instead of him.

The problem he has is that when he asks a question, he gets an error message saying "please enter at least one tag", despite the fact that he has included a tag into tags field. He says that he has the same problem when posting on meta.

Here is a screenshot illustrating this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I am not sure, whether this can be done; but if mods can change the question owner, it would be perhaps better to change the question owner to [Mehdi](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/67913/mehdi). Then he can edit the question, comment on the question etc., regardless of how much [privileges](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges) he has now.

Comment: Mods can't do that, only SE devs can.

Comment: @Mehdi: I've noticed that the red message won't go away when you enter the tag. Have you tried closing the red window (clicking on the $\times$) and posting the question? I only ask because everything else looks good.

Comment: @robjohn yes, I've tried it, it doesn't work

Comment: Does anybody have any suggestion? What can I do?

Comment: @Mehdi Does the same thing happened if you try adding two tags, for example [tag:differential-topology] and [tag:characteristic-classes]?

Comment: I've tried to search whether there was a similar question at meta.SO. I was only able to find this one: [SO does not allow me to post although I am selecting a TAG](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122834/so-does-not-allow-me-to-post-although-i-am-selecting-a-tag). But it does not seem to answer your problem.

Comment: @Martin yes, I've tried with several tags and different tags

Comment: Thank you for searching

Comment: @Mehdi: please tell us what browser and operating system you are using, whether this problem persists across computers and across different web browsers. Do you have any browser extensions installed? On occasions browser extensions can overwrite Javascript definitions and break Math.SE.

Comment: I'm using Windows7 and I've tried with both Mozila and Chrome, I don't remember if I've installed any extension or not!

Comment: Now, I tried it with IE and it worked! maybe it's because of extensions, Thank you very much

Comment: @Mehdi: add that to your answer and accept it :-)

Comment: @robjohn I added a new answer, how can I accept it?

Comment: @Mehdi: I had intended that you append/modify your first answer (which was not really an answer) to encompass your findings. There is no need for two answers. To accept, click on the check mark below the upvote/downvote arrows next to the answer that you want to accept.

Comment: @robjohn I don't see the check mark below the downvote arrow!(even in IE) maybe still browser problems.

Comment: @Mehdi: I forgot that you did not ask this question. Martin Sleziak is the only one who can accept answers on this question.

Comment: @Mehdi: I take it you are satisfied with the answer you've posted and I've accepted it.

Comment: @Martin of course, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did what was suggested in the comments, I tried with another browser (IE) and it worked, I still don't know whether it was because of browser extensions or not, many thanks to my friends who helped.